# MongoDB typical use

Tags: php, json, node.js, mongodb, mapreduce

I'm a beginner in MongoDB so i have a couple of question about it. First of all my code is written in PHP. My context of use is as follows:

- I have 80,000 documents stored in one collection
- Each document has this structure ( Keys can be from 1 to 20, with different values in each document ):

```json
{
    "_id": "58c91c8059b0a500083dab0c",
    "year": "2017",
    "month": "03",
    "day": "15",
    "data": {
        "key-1": "value-1",
        "key-2": "value-2",
        "key-n": "value-n"
    }
}
```

I would like to get all documents with a specific key and sum their value. So I used this code:

```php
$manager = new \MongoDB\Driver\Manager( MONGO_SERVER );

$filter = array ( 
    "year" => $_POST['time_year'], 
    "month" => $_POST['time_month'], 
    "day" => $_POST['time_day']
);

$options = [
    'projection' => ['_id' => 0],
];

$query = new \MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
$rows = $manager->executeQuery('REPORT.xxxxxxx', $query);

foreach ($rows as $entry) {
    [..]
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes)
```

So, from this problem I have this questions:

1. With MapReduce could be possible avoid this problem?

   - I looked into some examples of MapReduce with PHP but every example used MongoCode. Making some research I discovered the class MongoCode is deprecated and there's no alternative.
   - Is there any other way to get the same results ( MongoDB\Driver )?
2. Is PHP the best language for use MongoDB? Node.js could be a better choice?
3. Adding a bigger numbers of files ( 80,000 per day ) : could this be a problem for MongoDB?

Comment: Hi br1luca, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I have a few questions about your approach: firstly, you seem to be fetching all the records (for a particular date), and bringing them back to php before trying to sum their values. Would it not be better to do that filtering and summing on the db server, if at all possible?

Comment: How is possibile sums they value? For example. I want to sum al value inside data.key-1. Maybe i'm using MongoDB in the wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running into a problem vis-a-vis the memory pooling of MongoDB, and how to control it. Which is done in a variety of ways based upon you system.

However even before that, you are approaching the code from a PHP point of view. I think you should take a look and a grasp at $aggregate $unwind and other such MongoDB data manipulation functions.

Suggestion: Take some time to understand and configure the mongod.conf file and understand what the options can mean for your system. Then take the time to see the differences between how data can be retrieved by Mongo by using the documentation.

As for the best language with mongo..you will probably get a lot of answers. Node.js drivers are supported officially by Mongo, and Mongo has been using Node.js from the very start. (Think of PHP To MySQL as the same as Node.js To MongoDB). Though I am sure many will argue with that analogy. 
But as a PHP programmer myself, I would never think of using PHP with Mongo. Node is simply the natural partner for Mongo, as far as I have seen and observed over the past 2 years.